# What are all the "hidden" quests in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone you can unlock some gold bonus or whatever if you reach specific goals like reaching level 10 with all characters. I am not talking about the daily quests here.

Does anyone have a complete list of all the bonuses?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes there is one in the [wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest):

```
Quest Name                  Requirement                                     Reward
First Blood                 Complete a game in Play mode.                   1 Card Pack  
The Duelist                 Play 3 games in Play mode.                      100 Gold  
Level Up                    Get any class to level 10.                      100 Gold  
Crafting Time               Disenchant a card.                              95 Arcane Dust  
Enter The Arena             Enter The Arena                                 1 Arena Credit (Free Round)  
Arrrrrr!!!                  Acquire every Pirate.                           2x Captain's Parrot  
Golden Arrrrrr!!!           Acquire every Golden Pirate.                    2x Captain's Parrot (Golden)  
Mrglglglgl!                 Acquire every Murloc.                           Old Murk-Eye  
Golden Mrglglglgl!          Acquire every Golden Murloc.                    Old Murk-Eye (Golden)  
Chicken Dinner              Win 100 games in any mode.                      300 Gold  
Big Winner                  Win 1000 games in any mode.                     300 Gold  
Ready to Go!                Unlock every Hero.                              100 Gold  
Beta Hero!                  Thank you for helping to test our Store!        Gelbin Mekkatorque (Golden)  
Crushed Them All!           Defeat every Expert AI Hero.                    100 Gold  
Got the Basics!             Collect every card in the Basic Set.            100 Gold  
One of Everything!          Collect every card in the Expert Set.           100 Gold
Ready to Rock!              Thank you for attending BlizzCon 2013!          Elite Tauren Chieftain (Golden)
Golden Malfurion Stormrage  Win 500 Ranked games with Malfurion Stormrage.  Golden hero portrait  
Golden Rexxar               Win 500 Ranked games with Rexxar.               Golden hero portrait  
Golden Jaina Proudmoore     Win 500 Ranked games with Jaina Proudmoore.     Golden hero portrait  
Golden Uther Lightbringer   Win 500 Ranked games with Uther Lightbringer.   Golden hero portrait  
Golden Anduin Wrynn         Win 500 Ranked games with Anduin Wrynn.         Golden hero portrait  
Golden Valeera Sanguinar    Win 500 Ranked games with Valeera Sanguinar.    Golden hero portrait  
Golden Thrall               Win 500 Ranked games with Thrall.               Golden hero portrait  
Golden Gul'dan              Win 500 Ranked games with Gul'dan.              Golden hero portrait  
Golden Garrosh Hellscream   Win 500 Ranked games with Garrosh Hellscream.   Golden hero portrait  
Greater Reaper of Packs     Diablo III Reaper of Souls Collector's Edition  3 Card Packs  
Mount Up!                   Win 3 games in Arena or Play mode.              "Hearthsteed" World of Warcraft mount  
You are Legend              Reach Legend rank in Ranked Play mode.          "Legends" Card Back  
Fireside Friends            Play against other players on the same subnet   "Fireside Friends" Card Back  
Reaper of Packs             Purchase Diablo III Reaper of Souls             1 Card Pack 
iPack                       Awarded for playing a game on iPad.             1 Card Pack 
Android Tablet              Awarded for playing a game on Android tablet.   1 Card Pack 
iPhone                      Awarded for playing a game on iPhone.           1 Card Pack 
Android Phone               Awarded for playing a game on Android phone.    1 Card Pack 
Samsung Galaxy S6 series    Awarded for logging in on a S6 series phone.    "Galaxy Gifts" card back & 3 Card Packs  
Hero of the Storm           Reach level 12 in Heroes of the Storm.          "Heroes of the Storm" card back
```

The exact wording for the Fireside Friends quest is:

> Play 3 matches against other players on the same subnet, with at least 3 players total on that subnet.

The maximum amount of packs from Reaper Of Souls that can be redeemed to a single account is 5.

"Ready to Rock!" and "Beta Hero!" are no longer available.

The (Golden) Arrrrrr!!! and Mrglglglgl! quests only require the Pirates or Murlocs from the "Basic" and "Classic" sets. These quests will be retired when the [standard format](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505/a-new-way-to-play-2-2-2016#faq) comes around.

The card pack rewards are all "Classic" packs.

Comment: nice, one question  : "Thank you for helping to test our Store!" - Do I need to purchase something with real money? or just user the store with gold? Thanks

Comment: @ray You need to spend real money. I think arena counts too.

Comment: Arena does in fact count.  That's how I got my Gelbin Mekkatorque

Comment: I just earned the Big Winner achievement. I wasn't sure what "1000 games in any mode" meant beforehand, so in case anyone else is wondering, it is the sum total of arena+casual+ranked+practice

Comment: I've got 94 play mode wins, and 21 arena wins, and yet never received gold from unlocking 'Chicken Dinner', so I'm not sure the David's information above is accurate... Although I can't verify, I definitely think I would have noticed +300g considering I spend it ASAP.

Comment: You might want to add the android reward as well

Comment: I did get the 100 wins reward... Maybe is 100 wins with any hero? (I played with only one hero at that point).

Comment: Is this answer still valid as of patch 6.2.0 which came with a couple of new quests?

Comment: @Rob Those are AFAIK all daily quests. This post lists the hidden one time quests.