# Is there a way to track the progress of hidden quests in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Is there any way to track the progress of ['hidden' quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152057/what-are-all-the-hidden-quest-in-hearthstone) in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completed most of the quests and searched for this previously, and **no**, there is no way to track them at the moment. I do hope this feature will be implemented before launch.

Comment: Wouldn't the quests then stop being _hidden_? :)

Comment: @ykb no, they wouldn't. They are hidden because they don't tell you that you must get 100 wins to complete the quest. However knowing that you have 70 wins so far doesn't "unhide" the quest